# How do I show code coverage in Swift Packages?

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, swift-package

On my M1 mac, using Xcode 13.3, I created a package and displayed the code coverage bar (Editor menu –> Code Coverage).

After running tests, there is no indication of code coverage at all in the source code.

How do I get code coverage when testing a package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't turn on Code Coverage for the library's scheme. Turn it on:

[image]

See the checkbox at the bottom: Code Coverage? Check that checkbox.

Now run the package test and coverage will be gathered. The best way to see it, in my experience, is actually in the report navigator:

[image]

**Edit:** In more modern Xcode (14.3 and later) it's simpler. Tests default to using test plans, so just turn on code coverage in the test plan:

[image]

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer.

Comment: @mikro098 It's simpler now. Tests have test plans. Just turn on code coverage in the test plan and away you go. Packages are covered automatically.

Comment: This is still a valid answer, there is just another way of accomplishing the same thing through the test plans. Checking the box in the test scheme inside Xcode still works just fine, I did it just now.

Comment: @BriannaDoubt I think the objection was that the "Gather coverage" checkbox is no longer present in the scheme editor for new project. And that's true; test plans are the only alternative today. I encouraged WikipediaBrown to add the newer approach as an answer, but there was no response, so I appended it myself.

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't realize I wasn't on 14.3 :) Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 9):

As of (at least) Xcode 14, the former answer is no longer correct. For a Swift Package you need to enable this on the test plan.

Steps:

1. Show Test Navigator (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>)
2. Select the title, in the example: `TestPlanExample` and select "Edit Test Plan"

[image: Select Edit Test Plan]

3. Select the tab "Configuration" and scroll down to "Code Coverage"
4. Enable Code Coverage and either select "All targets" or select which targets you wish you generate code coverage for.
   [image: Enable Code Coverage]
5. Save the testplan

Comment: Thank you @Paul Peelen. I was looking for where could I select the code coverage targets. :)